# Image of a subgroup under the projection to the projective general linear group is isomorphic to the group quotiented by its centre

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, general-linear-group

Let $(V,\rho)$ be a finite, irreducible representation of a finite group $G$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. So:

$$
\rho: G \to \textrm{GL}(V)
$$

is a homomorphism.

Let $Z(V)$ denote the centre of $\textrm{GL}(V)$, and define the projective general linear group as the quotient:

$$
\textrm{PGL}(V) = \textrm{GL}(V)/Z(V)
$$

and the corresponding canonical projection:

$$
\pi: \textrm{GL}(V) \to \textrm{PGL}(V).
$$

I want to show that, if $Z(\rho(G))$ is the centre of $\rho(G) < \textrm{GL}(V)$, then:

$$
\pi(\rho(G)) \cong \rho(G)/Z(\rho(G)).
$$

I have been told that this follows immediately from Schur's lemma, but I do not see how.

I suppose that by arguing by induction on the order of $G$, we could assume that $\rho$ is faithful, so that we have $\rho(G)/Z(\rho(G)) \cong G/Z(G)$.

As the centre of the group is Abelian, it would follow from Schur's lemma that the restriction of $\rho$ to $Z(G)$ is the sum of irreducible degree 1 characters, but I do not see how this applies to the above.

All help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is $V$? A vector space over a field??

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου a vector space. Apologies. I have edited the question to specify this.

Comment: We may also assume that the vector space $V$ is over the field of complex numbers, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a try. From first isom. theorem we have $$\pi(\rho(G))\cong \rho(G)/ker\pi|_{\rho(G)}$$

It suffies to show that $ker\pi|_{\rho(G)}=Z(\rho(G))$. It is $$ker\pi|_{\rho(G)}=\{\rho(g)\in \rho(G)|\ \rho(g)\in Z(V)\}=\\ =\{\rho(g)\in \rho(G)|\ \rho(g)=k\cdot Id\}=\\=Z(\rho(G))$$

where the second equality folllows from Schur's Lemma.

Comment: Ah yes! By the fact that, if $\rho(g)\rho(h) = \rho(h) \rho(g)$ for all $h \in G$, then $\rho(g): V \to V$ is a $G$-homomorphism, and so it is an isometry by Schur's lemma, and so the above follows! Great!